# How to get folder by url ("Copy link" button)

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, folder

I have link to SharePoint online folder like: `https://domain/:x:/s/Site1/EcEHhjfer8tBhw84D4iadQUBdCcX_MGw-EpH_lQwXUPJjw?e=pBgWZS`

How can I get the folder using CSOM? I need to be able to read the list of files in folder and download them programmatically.

For files I've used something like this:

```
var file = context.Web.GetFileByUrl(sharedLink);
context.Load(file);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

But for folders I haven't found any suitable method.

Answer (score 0):

Your could connect the credentials to the SharePoint site and read and download files from a specific site and folders by using the following code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;

using ClientOM = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace MvcApplication.Models.Home
{
    public class SharepointModel
    {
        public ClientContext clientContext { get; set; }
        private string ServerSiteUrl = "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/ITVillahermosa";
        private string LibraryUrl = "Shared Documents/Invoices/";
        private string UserName = "someone.surname@somecompany.com";
        private string Password = "********";
        private Web WebClient { get; set; }

        public SharepointModel()
        {
            this.Connect();
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                using (clientContext = new ClientContext(ServerSiteUrl))
                {
                    var securePassword = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in Password)
                    {
                        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                    }

                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, securePassword);
                    WebClient = clientContext.Web;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }

        public string UploadMultiFiles(HttpRequestBase Request, HttpServerUtilityBase Server)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = null;
                for (int f = 0; f < Request.Files.Count; f++)
                {
                    file = Request.Files[f] as HttpPostedFileBase;

                    string[] SubFolders = LibraryUrl.Split('/');
                    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), filename);
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    clientContext.Load(WebClient, website => website.Lists, website => website.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    //https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/ITVillahermosa/Shared Documents/
                    List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents"); //Shared Documents -> Documents
                    clientContext.Load(documentsList, i => i.RootFolder.Folders, i => i.RootFolder);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    string SubFolderName = SubFolders[1];//Get SubFolder 'Invoice'
                    var folderToBindTo = documentsList.RootFolder.Folders;
                    var folderToUpload = folderToBindTo.Where(i => i.Name == SubFolderName).First();

                    var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
                    //Assign to content byte[] i.e. documentStream
                    fileCreationInformation.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                    //Allow owerwrite of document
                    fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
                    //Upload URL
                    fileCreationInformation.Url = ServerSiteUrl + LibraryUrl + filename;

                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);

                    //Update the metadata for a field having name "DocType"
                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = "UploadedCSOM";

                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }

                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }

        public string DownloadFiles()
        {
            try
            {
                string tempLocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\";
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempLocation);
                foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }

                FileCollection files = WebClient.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(this.LibraryUrl).Files;
                clientContext.Load(files);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                if (clientContext.HasPendingRequest)
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (ClientOM.File file in files)
                {
                    FileInformation fileInfo = ClientOM.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    var filePath = tempLocation + file.Name;
                    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }

                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then, invoke the functions from the controller:

```
using MvcApplication.Models.Home;
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication.Controllers
{
    public class SharepointController : MvcBoostraBaseController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection form)
        {
            try
            {
                SharepointModel sharepointModel = new SharepointModel();
                return Json(sharepointModel.UploadMultiFiles(Request, Server), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ThrowJSONError(ex);
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Download(string ServerUrl, string RelativeUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                SharepointModel sharepointModel = new SharepointModel();
                return Json(sharepointModel.DownloadFiles(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ThrowJSONError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to the following Blog article:

- [New SharePoint CSOM version released for SharePoint Online – May
  2017](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-office-365-may-2017/)